# Map of nearby ATMs as well as the type of cards it takes and the fees

Tags: android, maps

I am looking for Android application that can give me a map of nearby ATMs as well as the type of cards it takes and the fees.

Any price and license is fine.

---

I am mostly interested in the following locations:

- California, United States
- Massachusetts, United States
- Paris, France
- Seoul, South Korea

Comment: Not tried any, but [a quick search at AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=atm+nearby) seems to have some interesting candidates ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps App can search for ATMs, cashpoints in the UK, near your location, (world wide), and will display which bank they are associated with.  It is normally preinstalled on Android or it is available for free from [Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) - *you can also [download maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?hl=en&ref_topic=3092425) for a specific area while you are on WiFi so as to save data charges.*

Fees often depend on which card you are using, *including is it a card from that bank* but some ATM entries have been edited by users to give some details of fees/charges.

Many banks also have apps which will show you the nearest ATM for your bank.